# Display a popup-menu in front of a table

Tags: css

I've created an menu for each table row which is displayed on hover. Everything is working well except one thing: 
If I hover over last rows menu, the menu should popup in front of the tables container instead of creating a scrollbar inside the container..

[Screenshot of real application example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mSH4.png)

See the example here:

```css
.container {
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-container {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-container ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
.menu-container ul:hover {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-container ul li {
  display: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-container ul:hover li {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <table border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <ul> col1
          <li>menu 1</li>
          <li>menu 2</li>
          <li>menu 3</li>
          <li>menu 4</li>
          <li>menu 5</li>
          <li>menu 6</li>
          <li>menu 7</li>
          <li>menu 8</li>
        </ul>
      </div>    
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
   </tr>      
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ty7uwup/1/

[image: Actual and expected behaviour]

Do you have any tips for me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the important part of your code here rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: @Ahcsas: check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tkrLaxmu/

Comment: @SayedRafeeq: Just changing the height of the container doesn't help. The height is calculated and not editable. In this example i just set it to 70px for showing the problem.

Comment: Then set it to what you use so that viewers can see your actual problem

Comment: @MarkPerera: It doesn't matter if max-height is set to 70px or 700px. It just minimizing the table rows needed for the example shown here.

Comment: I mean that the code you provided works, so I can't answer your problem

Comment: Oh sorry, i see what you mean.. The problem is that the menu does not overlap the container bottom.. i will update the question

Comment: No, it does. But the menu behaves just like you want it to

Comment: @MarkPerera: See the attached screenshot/mockup for actual and expected behaviour

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to include javascript?

Comment: @AndrewBone: Javascript is wellcome. I just tought it's a simple css setting

Answer (score 0):

The problem is positioning in your css. 
The container shouldn't have position attribute to keep in it's position.

Later you should have absolute position to keep the li above all.

Here is the fixed css:

```
.menu-container {

}
.menu-container ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
.menu-container ul:hover {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: If you want the  < li >s be as wide as table column you should also delete the width: 100% from  ".menu-container ul li"

Comment: With this change i ran into the next issue when adding a hover menu on the last row. After scrolling the table the popup menu is shifted downwards..:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ty7uwup/3/

Comment: But then it is only as wide as the content

Comment: @MarkPerera I don't understand completely. do you want to have a wide menu or small? as your screenshots shows, this will work for you if you delete the width: 100% from ".menu-container ul li" such as: `.menu-container ul li { display: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `.menu-container`s position was set to relative, so the `ul` positioned relative to that (the 2 `relative` words here are not related!).
Removing `position: relative` from `.menu-container` will do what you want, but the size of the submenu `ul` will not be the same as the parent `li` items.

So I used `calc` for the width of the ul
(The value may have to be changed if tried elsewhere)

```css
.container {
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-container {
  
}
.menu-container ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
.menu-container ul:hover {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: calc((100% - 40px) / 5);
}
.menu-container ul li {
  display: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-container ul:hover li {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <table border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="menu-container">
         <ul>  col1
          <li>menu 1</li>
          <li>menu 2</li>
          <li>menu 3</li>
          <li>menu 4</li>
          <li>menu 5</li>
          <li>menu 6</li>
          <li>menu 7</li>
          <li>menu 8</li>
        </ul>
      </div>    
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      col 4
    </td>
   </tr>      
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

P.S. Weird glitch. Selecting the text of the ul scrolls the table to where that text would have been

Comment: The width is not the problem. But how to show the menu in front of all other elements?

Comment: Sorry! Remove `position: relative` from `.menu-container`